Nuxt Content reactive rendering
I want to implement MD rendering to my Nuxt app. It seams that Nuxt Content is best fit, because of the integrations, support, ECT. But I ran in to an issue. I am creating editor inside my web app, and I wasn't able to find a way to render the MD string from <textarea> live. I want to make the source text and the preview side by side with immediate sync. I was trying to use markdownParser.parse() but it doesn't seams to be the right solution and I wasn't able to find some reliable way to rerender it on source string change.
Does anyone know some "elegant" way to do it?
Thanks.
